# Swift WebView signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I'm trying to create a WebView in Swift and get error code "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" on the line `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`

My code is the following (the variable "theURL" does have a real URL):

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var Webview: UIWebView!

    var theURL = "URL"

    func loadWebPage() {
        let theRequestURL = NSURL (string: theURL)
        let theRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: theRequestURL!)
        Webview.loadRequest(theRequest)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadWebPage()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your `WebView` property connected to the web view by Interface Builder?

Comment: Could you post the entire stack trace of your exception? Also try to put an exception breakpoint to deduce. where exactly the code is breaking

Answer (score 0):

You have to link this page to your Main.Storyboard. You can use the Web View in the Main.Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question is from a while back but I was just having the exact same problem, I solved it by checking outlet connections in main.storyboard file. I had deleted an outlet from code but not from main.storyboard. click on all views and check their outlet connections.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem, i Hope :)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
...
   webView.uiDelegate = self
...
}
```

See this link please:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview#2560973

Answer (score -1):

One of the 2 reasons -

- Check for valid url object before unwrapping it

> ```
> if let theRequestURL = NSURL (string: theURL) {
>     let theRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: theRequestURL!)
>     Webview.loadRequest(theRequest)
> }
> ```

- Or Webview is not connected properly from the storyboard, nor initialised in the code